# ffmpeg not working in script - moov atom not found

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I made a simple script that divides a `flv` file into multiple parts, converts them all to `.mp4` individually and then merge all of them to form a final mp4 file. I did this to save time and convert large files in parallel.

However, I am stuck because the command that normally runs on command line for `ffmpeg`, doesn't run via script.

I am kind of stuck here and will like to have some assistance.

```
#!/bin/bash


#sleep 5


filenametmp=$1;

filename=`echo "$filenametmp" | awk '{split($0,a,"."); print a[1]}'`


echo $filename

output="$filename-output"

filenamewithoutpath=`echo "$output" | awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print a[4]}'`

echo $output $filenamewithoutpath

/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $filenametmp -c copy -map 0 -segment_time $2 -f segment $output%01d.flv

#sleep 10


#echo "/bin/ls -lrt /root/storage/ | /bin/grep $filenamewithoutpath | /usr/bin/wc -l"
filecounttmp=`/bin/ls -lrt /opt/storage/ | /bin/grep $filenamewithoutpath | /usr/bin/wc -l`

filecount=`expr $filecounttmp - 1`

echo $filecount

for i in `seq 0 $filecount`
do


suffix=`expr 0000 + $i`

filenametoconvert="$output$suffix.flv"
convertedfilename="$output$suffix.mp4"
echo $filenametoconvert

/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $filenametoconvert -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -vsync 1 -r 25 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 64k -ar 44100 -ac 1 $convertedfilename > /dev/null 2>&1 &


done





sleep 5

concatstring=""

for j in `seq 0 $filecount`
do


suffix=`expr 0000 + $j`

convertedfilenamemp4="$output$suffix.mp4"

#concatstring=`concat:$concatstring|$convertedfilenamemp4`

echo "file" $convertedfilenamemp4 >> $filename.txt

#ffmpeg -i concat:"$concatstring" -codec copy $filename.mp4

#ffmpeg -f concat -i $filename.txt -c copy $filename.mp4


done

echo $concatstring

ffmpeg -f concat -i $filename.txt -c copy $filename.mp4


rm $output*
rm $filename.txt
```

I run any flv file like this :

```
./ff.sh /opt/storage/tttttssssssssss_573f5b1cd473202daf2bf694.flv 20
```

I get this error message :

> moov atom not found

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version, standard installation of ffmpeg.

Comment: What does it mean it doesn't run? Do you have any output?

Comment: Hi Pacholik. Sure there is an output. Its moov atom not found. I am not an expert in ffmpeg and i dont know the details of this moov atom. I did figure out that it has something to do with the timing of ffmpeg operations. I will be happy to give you my console output if u so do require

Comment: I just had this exact same issue with a script that loops through video and audio files and merges them together. The last file to be merged would give me that "moov atom cannot be found" error. After putting a short sleep between each ffmpeg invocation, the error went away. Upon further testing, simply using a plain "wait" statement after each ffmpeg invocation also fixed the error.